# Startup Oracle Database with an NFS mount

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, oracle-linux

I currently have an Oracle Database which works just fine on 1 server.

I want to share the folder which contains its' control file to another server via an NFS mount.

However when mounted I get presented with the error:

```
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

The mount command I'm running is:

```
sudo mount -v -t nfs4 -o intr,bg,nolock,port=2222,mountport=3333,tcp localhost:/oracle/oradata/stby/ /u02/app/oracle/oradata/stby/
```

And my /etc/exports file from the attempted mount machine is:

```
/oracle/oradata/stby *(no_auth_nlm,insecure_locks,rw,sync,no_root_squash,nohide,insecure)
```

The mount in itself works! I just need to find a way in which the control file doesn't get 'locked' I guess.

Comment: What is our NFS server? Try to check file locks on NFS server.

Comment: Just another linux box - how would I check file locks? Sure the no-lock mount command would stop this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I recall nfs lockd stores some information in files in /var, to make file locks persistent.